# Uso del bucle while

Tags: java, string, condiciones, while, double

Soy nuevo en la programación, aún no tengo claro como funciona el ciclo while, tengo el siguiente ejercicio.
Ingresar el nombre y su altura por teclado la cantidad de veces que sea necesaria. El proceso se repetirá hasta que se introduzca un 0 y se deberá de imprimir la altura promedio.
He realizado el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejercicio12 {
    /*Ingresar el nombre y su altura por teclado la cantidad de veces que 
     sea necesaria. El proceso se repetirá hasta que se introduzca un 0 y 
     se deberá imprimir la altura promedio        
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  name; 
        double al=1;
        
        Scanner run=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
        name=run.next();
        while(al>0){
            al++;
        }        
    }
}
```

Disculpen la molestia pero no tengo mayor idea de como continuar, agradezco de antemano sus ayudas.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenidx a SOes. No nos has dicho cuál es el problema con el código. Tampoco podemos tomarlo y replicar dicho problema porque nos compartes una imagen. Por favor, edita la pregunta, aclara estos detalles, pon el código como texto y sé puntual en la pregunta, ¿qué problema tienes?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Estás pidiendo ayuda o mandando a que ayuden ?? Como sea debes corregir el post, principalmente el mensaje del mismo.

Comment: como lo puedo corregir o formular el problema

Comment: Como te lo han dicho antes @dieguex, primero pon un titulo acorde, que explique el tema. Luego lee como preguntar para realizar una buena pregunta. Pero se basa en explicar que tienes, que problema tienes, y que buscas solucionar. Ademas las imagenes no van, pega el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero pensaba corregir tu código pero no realiza nada, lo que hace tu código es un bucle infinito porque inicializas un valor mayor que 0 y dentro del bucle la variable va seguir incrementándose sucesivamente.

```
double al=1;
while(al>0){ //1>0 verdadero;2>0 verdadero;3>0 verdadero, etc
  al++; //al=2;3;4;5;....
}
```

Como veo que tienes muchas dudas, mi recomendación es que revises tutoriales sobre fundamentos de programación, en `Youtube` hay bastantes tutoriales y buenos.

Primero antes de comenzar a codificar a lo loco tienes que preguntarte, que es lo quieres que realice el programa, en este caso tú quieres.

1. Leer datos por teclado, entonces necesitas  la clase `Scanner` y las variables para `nombre` y `altura`
2. La lectura de datos se va realizar mientras el usuario no ingrese el número `0`, entonces vas necesitar una variable que para leer el número ya sea 0 o diferente que 0.
3. Deseas el promedio de las alturas, para ello tienes que saber que el promedio se halla `suma de alturas/cantidad de datos ingresados`, entonces vas necesitar 2 variables más  `sumaAlturas` para sumar las alturas ingresadas y `contador` para saber cuantos datos estás ingresando.

Ahora que ya sabemos lo que tenemos que hacer, comenzamos a codificar, te dejo un ejemplo funcional de lo que deseas que realiza tu ejercicio.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String nombre;
        double altura,sumaAlturas=0;       
        int continuar=1;//Inicializamos la variable con cualquier número diferente a 0
        int contador=0;
        
        Scanner run=new Scanner(System.in);        
        
        while(continuar!=0){
            System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre :");
            nombre=run.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ingrese la altura: ");
            altura=Double.parseDouble(run.nextLine());
            sumaAlturas=sumaAlturas+altura;
            contador++;
            System.out.print("Desea continuar (Para finalizar programa presionar 0, para continuar cualquier número?:");
            continuar=Integer.parseInt(run.nextLine());            
        }
        System.out.println("El promedio de edades ingresados es: "+sumaAlturas/contador);        
    }
```

Te explico el código.

1. Declaramos las variables, aquellas variables que se van ir incrementando su valor `sumaAlturas` y `contador`  lo inicializamos a 0.
2. La variable  `continuar` inicializó a `0` para que pueda ingresar al `while`, al final del código dentro del `while` se pide ingresar 0 o cualquier valor, depende de esta respuesta continuaremos dentro del `while` o saldremos de ella.
3. Finalmente mostramos por pantalla el promedio de alturas con la fórmula la conocido `suma de valores/cantidad de valores`.

**Aclaración**
Al momento de leer el valor de `altura` en la linea de código

```
altura=Double.parseDouble(run.nextLine());
```

Realizo `Double.parseDouble` porque hay `IDE` ejemplos (Netbeans,Eclipse, Visual Studio, Code, etc) cuando ingresamos valores decimales aveces lee con `,` o con `.` entonces para no depender del `IDE` mejor realizó `Double.parseDouble`.

La linea de código

```
continuar=Integer.parseInt(run.nextLine());
```

se puede realizar de la siguiente manera

```
continuar=run.nextInt();
run.nextLine();
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo